# Delete row after X amount of time in python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I'm making a discord bot for my shop, were I have a subscription based service. I made a redeem key system that saves users into a database, but I want to be able to delete the users from the database in X amount of time. X will depend in the subscription the user redeemed. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like

```
await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

to wait 10 seconds

Comment: What's asyncio?

Comment: it is a module for python, see the other answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider Asyncio Package for this. There are some information about its implementation on this link.
https://realpython.com/async-io-python/